# Forwarding ssh agent to container with Podman in Fedora

Tags: git, podman, ssh-agent

I am creating a podman image and I'm trying to understand how to allow the container use my host (Fedora 37) ssh-agent so as the container can clone git repositories. I would prefer this than using PAT or other solutions that I can think of.

I have set-up a very basic example:

The *application* `foo`:

```
#!/bin/bash -eux
git clone "$REPO"
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM docker.io/fedora:39@sha256:531209ee9007c2bf909c6548b0456524bde9da0a1ac95ecc67bf3b98e9046969 
ARG HOST
RUN dnf install -yq git
WORKDIR /app
COPY foo foo
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/app"
RUN useradd -m user && mkdir -p /home/user/.ssh && chown -R user:user /home/user/.ssh
WORKDIR /home/user
RUN printf "Host $HOST\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n" >> .ssh/config
USER user
ENTRYPOINT ["foo"]
```

Then I build the image:

```
podman build -t foo --build-arg HOST=$HOST .
```

And try to run it with:

```
$ podman run -it -v $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:$SSH_AUTH_SOCK:Z -e SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK -eREPO=$REPO foo

 + git clone git@*********.git

...
*****: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

If I run the container with `--entrypoint /bin/bash` and execute `ssh-add -L` I get:

```
[user@42e1646bd254 ~]$ ssh-add -L
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

I noticed that the "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" dir in the container is owned by root:

```
[user@246199390bfe ~]$ stat $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
  File: /run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   socket
Device: 0,68    Inode: 81          Links: 1
Access: (0755/srwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2023-03-19 07:28:45.436018916 +0000
Modify: 2023-03-18 06:20:31.860105581 +0000
Change: 2023-03-19 10:17:03.933082078 +0000
 Birth: 2023-03-18 06:20:31.860105581 +0000
```

And reading documentation I understood that podman runs as *root* within the container but gets mapped to my user outside the container (or something like that). So I tried to change my Dockerfile to use `root` instead of `user`:

```
FROM docker.io/fedora:39@sha256:531209ee9007c2bf909c6548b0456524bde9da0a1ac95ecc67bf3b98e9046969 
ARG HOST
RUN dnf install -yq git
WORKDIR /app
COPY foo foo
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/app"
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh
WORKDIR /root
RUN printf "Host $HOST\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n" >> .ssh/config
ENTRYPOINT ["foo"]
```

Re-built and then tried something like:

```
podman run -it -v $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/root/keyring:Z -e SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/root/keyring -eREPO=$REPO foo
```

But I still get a `Permission denied (publickey).`

I've checked that `stat $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` in the host contains `Context: system_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0:c235,c239` (so I believe the `:Z` option is working as intended.

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Using Podman 4.4.2 on Fedora.

**UPDATE**

I uninstalled `podman` and installed `docker-ce` and it worked on first attempt (tried the modified Dockerfile).

I would prefer to stay on podman though.

Comment: Try mapping the dir not the file. `-v "$(dirname "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK")":/root/keyring:Z -e SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/root/keyring/ssh`

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this problem too but I found a solution.

The key is adding `--privileged` in your run (let's leave security concerns for now)

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM fedora:37

RUN dnf install -yq git && dnf clean all
RUN mkdir -p .ssh
RUN printf "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n" >> .ssh/config
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

Build with the following:

```
podman build -t foo:temp
```

And ran with the following run:

```
$ podman run -it -v $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:$SSH_AUTH_SOCK:Z -e SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK --privileged foo:temp -c "ssh -T git@github.com"
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.113.4)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
Hi op-jenkins! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Idk why `StrictHostKeyChecking no` does not work, but once you just say yes, it can do ssh transaction.

I also tried with `--cap-add ALL` but that somehow failed:

```
$ podman run -it -v $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:$SSH_AUTH_SOCK:Z -e SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK --cap-add ALL foo:temp -c "ssh -T git@github.com"
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.112.4)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

When I turned -v option in `ssh -vT git@github.com`, along the debug messages, I did find this error:

```
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: Permission denied
```

So adding all linux privileges via `cap-add` is not enough somehow to get permissions.

I feel that there is some security lift up when doing `--privileged` but I am no expert. And in my host machine, we have SELinux enabled... so that might also play a factor...? idk.

But hopefully this helped.